# How to configure SSL with Axis2 using httpClient4

Tags: ssl, apache-axis, apache-httpclient-4.x

Since the httpClient 3 has been outdated, I need a replacement for the code:

```
SSLProtocolSocketFactory.setSSL(trustStore, keyStore, pasw);
ProtocolSocketFactory factory = new SSLProtocolSocketFactory();
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", factory, 443));
```

Please share if anyone has tried it.

In the java code, I'm tring to call the webservice using OperationClient object
     operationClientObject.execute(true);

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8):

The axis2 httpclient4 migration is not so easy, as it appears from the "documentation".

During the process, I use the latest Axis 2 version 1.7.8.

The axis 2 [1.7.0 release notes](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.7.0.html) contains a one liner, for HttpClient v4 integration:

```
Axis2 1.7.0 supports Apache HttpClient 4.x in addition to the no longer maintained Commons HttpClient 3.x. To enable the support for HttpClient 4.x, use org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPClient4TransportSender instead of org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender in axis2.xml. Please note that the code was written for HttpClient 4.2.x and should work with 4.3.x and 4.4.x, but is incompatible with 4.5.x.
```

Watch out the last words. Axis 2 1.7.8 pom file, and the binary distribution contains the httpclient-4.5.3.jar, but doesn't work with it. So use [httpclient 4.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4.1) instead.

**Enable logging**

Before the upgrade, I suppose you already have a working axis 2 project. I recommend to enable axis 2 debug logging, to see what happens. To enable logging define a custom log4j propery file with jvm argument:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/work/sources/debug_log4j.properties
```

The content of the debug_log4j.properties file is:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n
```

**Axis2 + Httpclient4**

If you doesn't have axis2.xml, you can found it in [axis2 binary package](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html) (contains all the dependencies and example configs)

Based on the release notes, you need to change the transport senders from  CommonsHTTPTransportSender to HTTPClient4TransportSender.

If you look (or debug) axis2 configurator, you see, the xml must contain specific parts otherwise axis2 doesn't read it.

So my axis2.xml content after configured to use HttpClient4 (and removed unused parts, but keep essential ones):

```
<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Transport Outs -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <parameter name="hotdeployment">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="hotupdate">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableSwA">false</parameter>   

    <transportSender name="local"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender"/>

    <transportSender name="http"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPClient4TransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>

        <!-- If following is set to 'true', optional action part of the Content-Type will not be added to the SOAP 1.2 messages -->
        <!--  <parameter name="OmitSOAP12Action">true</parameter>  -->
    </transportSender>

    <transportSender name="https"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPClient4TransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
    </transportSender>

     <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Phases  -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <phaseOrder type="InFlow">
        <!--  System predefined phases       -->
        <phase name="Transport">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="GenericProviderDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--  System predefined phases       -->
        <!--   After Postdispatch phase module author or service author can add any phase he want      -->
        <phase name="OperationInPhase">
            <handler name="MustUnderstandChecker"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandChecker">
                <order phase="OperationInPhase"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
        <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
        <!--system predefined phase-->
        <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="InFaultFlow">
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="GenericProviderDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationInFaultPhase"/>
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFaultFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
        <phase name="OperationOutFaultPhase"/>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
</axisconfig>
```

In the java side, you need to create a custom axis2 configuration context, to use our custom axis2.xml. Axis2 offer multiple configurator, i prefer the file based one:

```
final ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(
    "c:\\work\\sources\\axis2conf",
    "c:\\work\\sources\\axis2conf\\axis2.xml");
```

You can assign the configuration context to the client stub during the constructor:

```
FileNet_UploadDocumentWSStub stub = new FileNet_UploadDocumentWSStub(ctx, "https://testserver/test.asp");
```

So, if you doesn't want to use custom ssl settings, your upgrade is done.

**Axis2 + Httpclient4 + SSL**

After you upgraded to httpclient4, the implementation doesn't use the custom protocol handler property (HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER) anymore.

The old implementation in org/apache/axis2/transport/http/impl/httpclient3/HTTPSenderImpl.java:524:

```
// one might need to set his own socket factory. Let's allow that case
// as well.
Protocol protocolHandler = (Protocol) msgCtx.getOptions().getProperty(
                HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER);
```

The new implementation org/apache/axis2/transport/http/impl/httpclient4/HTTPSenderImpl.java:583:

```
   // TODO : one might need to set his own socket factory. We have to allow that case as well.
```

You need to setup ssl context in httpclient4 side. It's not a problem, because axis allow you to define httpclient for a ws call with HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT property:

```
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

But if you create a httpclient4 for a standard way:

```
...
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create(); 
...
```

and assign it to axis2 client stub, you got a ClassCastException, because all new httpclient Builder, factory, etc. methods create the "modern" implementation of httpclient, based on ClosableHttpClient. But axis2 implementation depends on deprecated AbstractHttpClient. So you need to create old version of httpclient.

The complete example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext;
import org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

public class SslTest {

  public SslTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File keyFile = new File("c:\\work\\sources\\ConsoleApp25\\avp-pc.jks");

    final ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(
    "c:\\work\\sources\\axis2conf",
    "c:\\work\\sources\\axis2conf\\axis2.xml");    


    FileNet_UploadocumentWSStub stub = new FileNet_UploadDocumentWSStub(ctx, "https://testserver/test.asp");
    FileNet_UploadDocument wsMethodReq = new FileNet_UploadDocument();
    ServiceClient serviceClient = stub._getServiceClient();
    Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();

    //keystore types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keystore-types
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
    in = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
    keyStore.load(in, "changeit".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    //Factory instance types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#T5
    //on IBM servers use IbmX509 instead of SunX509
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
    Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);
    ClientConnectionManager cm =  new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);


    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
    stub.fileNet_UploadDocument(wsMethodReq);

    System.out.println("done");
  }
```

Comment: Awesome job - you really helped to got thru the axis2 mess with custom keystores!! Thank you

Comment: This configuration works for httpclient 4.5 version ?

Comment: As mentioned above: Axis 2 1.7.8 pom file, and the binary distribution contains the httpclient-4.5.3.jar, but doesn't work with it. So use httpclient 4.4.1 instead.