# Configure Apache HttpClient 4.5 as a transport sender in Axis2 stub

Tags: java, ssl, apache-axis, apache-httpclient-4.x, soap-client

I am in the process of replacing Apache Httpclient 3.1 to 4.5 version, Our application is using AXIS 2 SOAP Web Service stub which underneath is using HTTPClient 3.1 TransportSender. I need to migrate it to use HttpClient 4.5 version. Below is the complete code that need to be migrated to HttpClient 4.5 version :

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol; // 3.1 version
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SecureProtocolSocketFactory; // 3.1 version


final Options clientOptions = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, new Protocol("https", new TLSSocketFactory(), 443));




public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {
private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;
public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}
@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}
@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}
@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}
@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}
@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inetAddress, int i1, HttpConnectionParams httpConnectionParams) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, i, inetAddress, i1));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}
@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}
private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
```

}

## I came across this StackOverflow post : [How to configure SSL with Axis2 using httpClient4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554807/how-to-configure-ssl-with-axis2-using-httpclient4/53171162#53171162)

## But its clearly mentioned in the post that it is only compatible upto httpclient 4.4.1.

> Axis2 1.7.0 supports Apache HttpClient 4.x in addition to the no
>   longer maintained Commons HttpClient 3.x. To enable the support for
>   HttpClient 4.x, use
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPClient4TransportSender
>   instead of org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender
>   in axis2.xml. Please note that the code was written for HttpClient
>   4.2.x and should work with 4.3.x and 4.4.x, but is incompatible with 4.5.x.

## We are using HttpClient 4.5 and it clearly says it's incompatible with 4.5.x

I am really stuck and need help on migrating the above piece of code to use HttpClient 4.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Did you found a solution.?

Comment: @JhoubertRincon, The steps mentioned in the SO post worked for me. It works for HttpClient 4.5.x as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554807/how-to-configure-ssl-with-axis2-using-httpclient4/53171162#53171162

Answer (score 0):

The steps mentioned in the below SO Post works for HttpClient 4.5.x as well.

[configure SSL with Axis2 using httpClient4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554807/how-to-configure-ssl-with-axis2-using-httpclient4/53171162#53171162)